# AWS SNS "maxReceivesPerSecond" policy isn't working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, throttling

As per AWS documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-features-for-amazon-sns-delivery-policies-and-message-formatting/)

> **maxReceivesPerSecond** – Maximum number of delivery attempts per second
> per Subscription.

I have configured the value as 1, which means the subscriptions should trigger 1 call every second. However it is taking roughly 30 minutes to trigger 20 calls. Can someone advise on how to set it up so an API call is triggered every second ?

[image: Pipedream log confirming that calls were received not 1 per second]

If this attribute (maxReceivesPerSecond) isn't configured, API calls are triggered instantly as below.

[image: Pipedream receives all APIs instantly]

Here's my SNS Policy set to throttle requests to 1 per second

> {   "http": {
> "defaultHealthyRetryPolicy": {
> "numRetries": 3,
> "numNoDelayRetries": 0,
> "minDelayTarget": 20,
> "maxDelayTarget": 20,
> "numMinDelayRetries": 0,
> "numMaxDelayRetries": 0,
> "backoffFunction": "linear"
> },
> "disableSubscriptionOverrides": false,
> "defaultThrottlePolicy": {
> "maxReceivesPerSecond": 1
> }   } }

Comment: You might try changing those `20` values to something smaller, to see if there's an unanticipated interaction between retry timers and throttling.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with `maxReceivesPerSecond`. Remove the throttle policy and wait for AWS to fix the problem. See https://cloudonaut.io/loosing-trust-in-aws-sns-broken-for-24-days/ and https://marbot.io/blog/how-to-fix-delayed-alarms.html for details.